# R: display subtotals in crosstables

Tags: r, tidyverse, crosstab

For a report I need to create some crosstables with several hierarchies (using r-markdown).

Let's make some fake data:

```r
n <- 100
df <- data.frame(
                 language = sample(c("Ger", "Eng", "Spa"), size = n, replace = TRUE),
                 sex = sample(c("female", "male"), size = n, replace = TRUE),
                 agegrp = sample(c("<=30", ">30"), size = n, replace = TRUE),
                 smoker = sample(c("yes", "no"), size = n, replace = TRUE)
                 )
```

Now I can create simple crosstables using `table()` and `addmargins()` for the totals:

```r
        Agegroup
Language <=30 >30 Sum
     Eng   16  16  32
     Ger   14  13  27
     Spa   17  24  41
     Sum   47  53 100
```

That's fine, but now I need to create some advanced crosstables with hierarchies. That's why I'm using the `ftable()`-function. As an example:

```r
> ftable(Language = df$language, Sex = df$sex, Smoker = df$smoker)
                Smoker no yes
Language Sex                 
Eng      female         7   9
         male           7   9
Ger      female         5  11
         male           4   7
Spa      female        12  10
         male          11   8
```

Is there a way or are there any special packages to calculate the totals or subtotals?

For example I would like to calculate the totals rowwise and/or columnwise:

```
                Smoker no yes Sum
Language Sex                 
Eng      female         7   9  16
         male           7   9  16
Ger      female         5  11  16
         male           4   7  11
Spa      female        12  10  22
         male          11   8  19
Sum                    46  54 100
```

Or is there any function or "grammar" to define which subtotals to calculate? For example:

```
                Smoker no yes
Language Sex                 
Eng      female         7   9
         male           7   9
         Subtotal      14  18
Ger      female         5  11
         male           4   7
         Subtotal       9  18
Spa      female        12  10
         male          11   8
         Subtotal      23  18
```

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: You might want to consider the package `crosstable` which has a `total` argument. More info in [the doc](https://danchaltiel.github.io/crosstable/). (disclaimer, I'm the maintainer of the package)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ftable(addmargins(table(df[c('language', 'sex', 'smoker')])))
                smoker  no yes Sum
language sex                      
Eng      female          9  10  19
         male           10   9  19
         Sum            19  19  38
Ger      female          7   5  12
         male            9   8  17
         Sum            16  13  29
Spa      female         11   8  19
         male            9   5  14
         Sum            20  13  33
Sum      female         27  23  50
         male           28  22  50
         Sum            55  45 100



ftable(addmargins(table(df[c('language', 'sex', 'smoker')]), 2))
                smoker no yes
language sex                 
Eng      female         9  10
         male          10   9
         Sum           19  19
Ger      female         7   5
         male           9   8
         Sum           16  13
Spa      female        11   8
         male           9   5
         Sum           20  13
```

Comment: Thanks! Sometimes the solution is very close.